# How to add description to installed package AND how to add description to package version?

Tags: unlocked-package

1. When I create an unlocked package, I want to also specify the description for it. How can I do it?

[image]

2. When I create a new package version I use the -e flag to indicate description however I don't see it anywhere

> sfdx force:package:beta:version:create -p "MyPackage" -e "my
> description which does not appear...." -x -w 100

to summarize, I have three questions:

1. how do I populate the Description under Setup->Installed Packages for packages?
2. Where do I see the description I add to the each package version using the -e flag?
3. What is the difference between -e (VERSIONDESCRIPTION) and -t (TAG ) flags?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I populate the Description under Setup->Installed Packages for packages?

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm), isn't very clear since it could be construed as applying only to managed 2GPs, but you can define the package `versionDescription` in your unlocked package's `sfdx-project.json`, like this:

```
{
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "My Package Name",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": "My package version description",
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

If you already created a version without a description, you can add it by using the `sfdx force:package:version:update` (or beta equivalent) command, using the `sfdx-project.json` or `-e` CLI value.

> Where do I see the description I add to the each package version using the -e flag?

You can see these descriptions by running the `sfdx force:package:list` on your CLI. You also see the package description in the Installed Packages list on your target org.

[image: Installed Packages with Descriptions]

> What is the difference between -e (VERSIONDESCRIPTION) and -t (TAG ) flags?

As to the CLI override options `-e` (for overriding the versionDescription) and `-t` (for setting the tag), I can't answer that since I'm not sure what the version tag is - it doesn't seem to be the alias or name (though it could be one of these).

I'm guessing this is intended to allow you to express the git tag related to this package version.

Comment: hi Phil, thank you for your answer. From my understanding, sfdx force:package:list will show only package description and not package version description. btw, when I run sfdx force:package:version:list I get a big table but none of the columns is the description.

Comment: Also the UI doesn't show me the description, I tried to add both in the sfdx-project.json and with a flag -e

Comment: Weird. We only use the version description and that is what my answer shows here.

Comment: Is this a plain unlocked package or some other variant, such as org dependent?

Comment: plain unlocked package, I can add more information to the question if you are looking for something specific

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of a reason. Did you have the version description set in the `sfdx-project.json` or on the CLI via `-e` when you created the package itself?

Comment: both... I expected to override it with the -e flag

Comment: Very odd. Have you tried the `force:package:version:update` and/or `force:package:beta:version:update` command to update the description for a given version?

Comment: Hi Phil, quick update, I opted to put the description in the Version Name, not ideal but at least now when I run package:version:list I get to see what I have in each version. tried force:package:version:update but it didn't work

Comment: Very strange. There has to be some underlying difference between what you have and what we did since we do not have the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but here are a few tidbits that I think we can arrange into something useful:

1. There is a "Package Visualizer" appexchange app that is quite good at showing packages and versions for a given dev hub. It has a field for `package description` and a field for `package version description`. They are different and are set in different commands, as you know.
2. The `package description` is shown in the Installed Packages list in an org, with a bold Description label.
   [image: Installed Packages listing for Apex Rollup showing version name, version number, and package description]

   Please note that the columns are the Package Name, the Publisher, the Version Number, and the Package Description.

   I made a managed package and set the Version Description and Package Description to different values, and I cannot see where the Version Description is ever shown to end-users.
3. There is no place in the project to display or to edit the `package description`, so it is entirely possible that James set that description to the same value... but it's not in his repo, and I highly doubt that he would manually set it with every version release; I also doubt he changes the description for every `package version`.
4. Since `package version description` appears to be used in zero places outside of the ISV's CLI objects (`package version`), I think it can safely be ignored for now. After all, if a description is written but never seen, is it really a description?

Having said all that, I think that the answer you seek is this:

- `Package Version Description` - set via `sfdx-project.json` and only useful for internal use by the ISV/developer
- `Package Description` - set via sf cli command `sf package update --description <description>` [sf cli reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_package_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_package_update_unified) and visible in Installed Packages list